# How to add IAP after releasing free game

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, app-store, google-play, in-app-billing

I've published a free game with ads on google play store.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oxene.games.xelevation

some players suggesting to have IAP to remove ads.
I would like to know whether it is possible to add IAP to a already released free game?

Comment: you can't convert free app to paid app later, so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> you can't convert free app to paid app later

In-app billing can be implemented in both paid and free apps.

> I would like to know whether it is possible to add IAP to a already
>   released free game?

Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

Go to google play console -> Your App -> Store Presence -> In-App Products then creat your IAP on the released game.